# change user and execute one command under bash

Tags: bash

Basically, I want to switch to user postgres and get a listing of databases.  This is with a Fabric script that reads command lines from a text file one by one, executes them and then saves their output to file.

`su - postgres && psql -c '\l'`

When I do this under bash directly:

```
(ssha)root ~$su - postgres && psql -c '\l'
postgres@localvm:~$
```

I saw a related question, [linux - Executing multiple commands under as another username within a file in BASH shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31058071/executing-multiple-commands-under-as-another-username-within-a-file-in-bash-shel), but that wouldn't work with my 1-line-per-command scheme and I don't need a full script, just 1 command.

Comment: `su` is used to substitute the user and run an interactive shell as the new user. The tool you are looking for is `sudo` whose purpose is to run only one command as another user.

Comment: @axiac fair point.  I tend to forget that because I am (or Fabric is) already under root, so don't automatically think of `sudo`.  ttg's second recipe worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `su -c`:

```
su - postgres -c "psql -c '\l'"
```

Though often you'll also have `sudo`, which is more robust and easier to use:

```
sudo -u postgres psql -c '\l'
```